# What are the differences between Taobao's open source projects: Metamorphosis and Timetunnel?

Tags: apache-kafka, log-analysis

I'd like to build a logs aggregation system and I found these tools developed by Taobao. Both of them can be used to collect logs for further processing and analysis. What's the different betweent them?

Answer (score 0):

if you can read Chinese, there has more details http://rdc.taobao.com/team/jm/archives/921.

1. using test based protocol like memcached.
2. metamorphosis is written in Java.
3. using self defined storage structure.
4. support sync and async subscribe api.
5. improve server recovery performance.
6. add interface for real time status, like memcached status.
7. support client side connection reuse.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. I know Kafka and its relationship with metamorphosis. But what makes me confused is that, the **Metamorphosis** has similar features to the **Timetunnel**. Are there any difference between them? What kinds of jobs are they serving in Taobao?